# Maple, Graph of an optimization problem

Tags: maple

I have solved the following maximisation problem analytically. I would like to graph the solution as well so I can see it, but I am not sure how to do this with Maple, i have just started using it.

Maximise x+y
subject to: $$ \begin {eqnarray*} x + 2y &\le& 4, \\ x + 2y &\le& 4, \\ x - y &\le& 1, \end {eqnarray*} $$where $x,y\ge0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this,

```
with(plots):

sol := Optimization:-Maximize( x+y, {2*x+y<=4, x>=0, y>=0} );

optpt := [eval(x,sol[2]), eval(y,sol[2]), sol[1]];  # optimal [x,y,z]

common := style=patchnogrid, transparency=0.4:
xrng,yrng,zrng := x=0..10, y=0..10, z=-10..10:

display( pointplot3d( [optpt], symbol=solidsphere, symbolsize=30,
                      color=red ),
         plot3d( x+y, xrng, yrng, style=patch ),
         implicitplot3d( x=0, xrng, yrng, zrng, common ),
         implicitplot3d( 2*x+y-4, xrng, yrng, zrng, common ),
         axes=box, view=[0..4,0..5,0..10] );
```

Another way is to invoke the Optimization:-Interactive() command, which brings up a pop-up assistant. In that assistant, enter the constraints and objective, toggle it as `maximize`, hit the Solve button, then the Plot button, and then change the returned object to be the Plot, and then Quit it. That should produce a similar 3D plot.

This question probably belongs more on [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com) (with the Maple tag) than here, as it's more a Maple programming question than a math question. You can also ask questions on [www.mapleprimes.com](http://www.mapleprimes.com)